# Анимации из blender не работают в unity

Tags: unity3d, анимация, blender

Анимации из blender не работают в unity. Я скачал персонажа с сайта Mixamo, и все анимации с этого сайта работают на нем, но мне нужно было сделать одну анимацию самому в blender.

Поэтому я экспортировал персонажа в T-позе в blender и сделал для него анимацию. При экспорте обратно в unity и переключении анимации на гуманоидную, я добавляю старый аватар персонажа, на котором все анимации работали, и вдруг выдается такая ошибка:

```
Avatar Rig Configuration mis-match. Transform hierarchy does not match: 
Transform 'Armature' not found in HumanDescription
```

Но при переключении на `Generic` анимация работает, но мне кажется, что это не правильно, и все анимации должны делаться на одном аватаре. Так ли это и как решить эту проблему?

Еще одна особенность - если импортировать модель, только что экспортированную из blender'а, обратно в blender, то у нее ни с того ни с сего появляются новые кости, добавляются кости на пальцах рук, ног и головы. В общем, как решить эту проблему?